# Does finishing the game with 100% make a difference?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep

Is it ok to just get all of Xenahort's files or does collecting all secrets make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are playing on Standard Mode, then if you get 100% completion in each character's story (Ventus, Aqua, Terra), you will unlock the Secret Ending. See [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/943347-kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep/60083946):

> In order to view the secret ending if even one of your characters' files are in Standard Mode (given that the other ones are in Standard, Proud, or Critical), you must attain 100% completion in all of your characters' journals. This is the equivalent of attaining 100% completion in the Trinity Archives. Believe it, sir.

If you are playing on Beginner (in *any* of your files), you ***cannot*** unlock the secret ending, no matter what.

However, if you play on either Proud or Critical for *all* of your files, then you will unlock the secret ending just by beating the final mission with each character.

Comment: I'm playing on critical mode. So I was just being maniac trying to get 100% =D

Comment: @Marco, then getting 100% completion will only bring you the joy of knowing you did it. Nothing special will get unlocked, though.